# How to install Node.js package without network?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cloud-messaging, npm-install

I'm developed on Linux OS without network.

Because of this, the npm command is not able to install the package.

So while looking for a way to install it, I found a way to download a zip file from github.

I unpacked the zip file and re-bundled it with tar. I tried npm install, but the installation failed with an EAI_AGAIN error.

Looking at this error, it seemed to be an error caused by not connecting the internal dependencies to the network.

I can move files from a networked Windows system to the Linux system, but on the Linux system it is difficult to connect to the network. How do I install it?

Comment: If none of the package to be installed depends on `native` code, you could just run required npm packages via npm install on your other machine. zip the 'node_modules' folder and move it. Don't forget to copy both package.json and package-lock.json as well

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need to make sure that you have the "package-lock.json" file on your root folder.
2. unzip the File you downloaded, I think it should be "Node_modules" then put that folder in the root folder of your project.

Try running `'npm install'` again

I hope it'll pick up

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

1. Place the module you want to install in the `node_modules` folder then install it with `npm install --cache-min 9999999 <module-name>`
2. You can use the package `local-npm`. But you need a network connection to install it.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
1. I tried the first one, but I saw the same error message.
2. I installed npm by moving the tar file. Can I download and unpack local-npm in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

**How to install your program inside of a server non connected to internet on linux system**

---

---

---

First, install your node program on a machine that have internet and have the same operating system.

---

Second, create a zip containing all the software repository *(sources + package.json + package-lock.js + nodes_modules)* and the directory called **.node-gyp** that you can find in your home *(it's an hidden directory)*.

---

Third, download the whole zip on your target server you want to make the install on.

---

Fourth, unzip the directory somewhere, and copy the **.node-gyp** directory at the home of the user that will execute your software.

---

Finally, run the command **npm rebuild**